# Variable watch while running in debug but not suspending app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to set watches for when a set of variables change state.  I can set these up in debug and they work fine while I'm stopped at a breakpoint and stepping through code, but what I need is to be able to see when they change state without suspending the app (Because I have timers (runnables) going and stopping messes things up.)  When running the watch values are blank.

I really don't want to have to put a bunch of lines in my code to send to the log each time one of the variables changes state.  I tried setting a "Field WatchPoint" on them.  I unchecked the "Suspend" box and checked "Log Message to console" and "Field Modification" is checked, but I don't get any messages out even though I know the value has changed.

Thanks for any assistance you can give.